# Lagom Cassandra Driver

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, lagom

According to some research about Lagom and Cassandra, I found that:

1. Lagom uses DataStax Java Driver for Cassandra, and
2. DataStax Java Driver only supports Cassandra 3.0.x ([link](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.2/manual/native_protocol/#compatibility-matrix))

So, if I want to use Cassandra 3.11 and Lagom, what should I do:

1. Should I configure Lagom with another Cassandra driver like  Achilles, PlayORM, ... ([link](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/drivers.html)). Is that possible?
2. is DataStax support Cassandra 3.11 in the enterprise edition?

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1):

DataStax Java Driver 3.2.0 that is used by Lagom should work with Cassandra 3.11 out of the box (just checked it myself using simple queries).

Even if it won't work out of the box, you can explicitly override driver version in Maven or other build system.

Comment: How can I check that Lagom uses the version 3.2.0, do you have a link?

Comment: latest version of `lagom-persistence-cassandra-core` (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lightbend.lagom/lagom-persistence-cassandra-core_2.12/1.4.0-M3) depends on `akka-persistence-cassandra` 0.59 (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-persistence-cassandra_2.12/0.59) that depends on `cassandra-driver-core` 3.2.0 (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core/3.2.0). If you're using Maven, then you can use `mvn dependency:tree` to show all dependencies of your project

Comment: Thank you, I used activator to build SBT project, and I'm new with that. Another question please: Do you know why DataStax doesn't support Cassandra 3.11 and they stopped with 3.0.9? Should I buy their enterprise edition?

Comment: I can't say why they don't list 3.11 as compatible with driver, but if the version of protocol wasn't changed, then it should work.

Comment: Note that activator is no longer developed or supported https://www.lightbend.com/blog/introducing-a-new-way-to-get-started-with-lightbend-technologies-and-saying-goodbye-to-activator. I would recommend migrating to the standard sbt.